# Swagger doesn't pick up customized API Info and always shows default values

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

While I am trying to integrate Swagger into a very simple Spring Boot REST app, Swagger-UI.html won't display and pick up my customized API Info. How should I make changes to below code so Swagger UI page will display the customized API Information? I cannot debug the SwaggerConfig class as well, put breakpoints in but when run as Spring Boot app, breakpoints won't stop.

What I have in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

My SwaggerConfig Class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket messageApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .groupName("cool-report-api")
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .select()
                .paths(messageApiPaths()).build();
    }

    private Predicate<String> messageApiPaths() {
        return or(regex("/api/topics.*"), regex("/api/message.*"));
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("Cool Message Receiver API")
                .description("Cool Message Receiver REST API Reference")
                .termsOfServiceUrl("http://www.cool-message-receiver.com")
                .contact(new Contact("John Smith", null, "john.smith@cool.com"))
                .license("Cool Proprietary Software")
                .licenseUrl("www.cool-message.com")
                .version("0.1.0")
                .build();
    }

}
```

But after I spring-boot:run the above code, the customized API Info doesn't seem to work and Swagger still displays the default “Api Documentation” title and "Apache 2.0" license etc. Here is what I am seeing now:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the messageApisPath().

Make sure you add the following library:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>16.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

It contains a lot of predicate functions. Make sure your 'or' is coming from there.

The following works for me

```
private Predicate<String> messageApiPaths() {
    return Predicates.or(PathSelectors.regex("/api/topics.*"), PathSelectors.regex("/api/message.*"));
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the inputs, tried but it didn't solve the problem. The symptom is the API info doesn't get picked up. The API paths are fine.

Comment: I am sorry to hear. :(

Answer (score 0):

The apiInfo should be call after the build like this:

```
@Bean
public Docket messageApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .groupName("cool-report-api")
            .select()
            .paths(messageApiPaths())
            .build()
            .apiInfo(apiInfo());
}
```