# Swagger 2.0: swagger-ui page showing default api info instead of the custom api info which I am setting

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am using docket api to configure swagger in a spring mvc project. The swagger-ui is correctly showing all the paths. However, the custom API information like title, description, license, etc. are showing only the default values and not the values which I am setting.

Debugging:
In the method "apiDocket()" in the class "SwaggerConfiguration", I checked the value of the field "apiInfo" for the object "docket" just before the return statement (using reflection). The values are correctly getting set. So clearly the problem is elsewhere which I am not being able to detect. 
I am using sprinfox-swagger version 2.9.2. I have tried with 2.9.1, 2.8.0, 2.7.0 and 2.6.1 just to check. I got the same results.
The problem which I am facing has been raised at [Swagger doesn't pick up customized API Info and always shows default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47742734/swagger-doesnt-pick-up-customized-api-info-and-always-shows-default-values) and [Spring boot swagger :custom information about Api not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50347994/spring-boot-swagger-custom-information-about-api-not-working) but I have not got my solution.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Docket apiDocket() {

        ApiInfo apiInfo = getApiInfo();
        Docket docket = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
        docket.apiInfo(apiInfo);
        return docket;
    }

    private ApiInfo getApiInfo() {

        return new ApiInfo(
                "TITLE",
                "DESCIPRION",
                "VERSION",
                "TERMS OF SERVICE URL",
                new Contact("NAME","URL","EMAIL"),
                "LICENSE",
                "LICENSE URL",
                Collections.emptyList()
        );
    }
}
```

In the servlet config xml file, I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- The controllers are autodetected POJOs labeled with the @Controller 
        annotation. -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sample.package"
        use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter
            expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation" />
        <context:include-filter type="annotation"
            expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice" />
        <!-- <context:include-filter type="regex" expression=".*SwaggerConfiguration.*"/> -->
    </context:component-scan>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>

    <!-- Turns on support for mapping requests to Spring MVC @Controller 
        methods Also registers default Formatters and Validators for use across all 
        @Controllers -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="com.sample.package.CustomRequestHandler"/>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <!-- Enable scanning of spring @Configuration classes -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    </bean>
    <bean id="swagger2Config"
        class="springfox.documentation.swagger2.configuration.Swagger2DocumentationConfiguration">
    </bean>
    <mvc:resources order="1" location="/resources/"
    mapping="/resources/**" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="swagger-ui.html"
    location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**"
    location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/" />
</beans>
```

In my pom.xml I have

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.2</version>
            </dependency>
```

In the swagger-ui page, I expect the title to be "TITLE", description to be "DESCRIPTION, version to be "VERSION", as evident from the method "getApiInfo()" in the code snippet. However, I am getting title as "Api Documentation", description as "Api Documentation", and version as "1.0". These are all default values and the values which I am setting in the code are not getting reflected in the swagger-ui page.
Please help!

Comment: Though this is not expected to solve the problem, but please switch to use ApiInfoBuilder : private ApiInfo apiInfo()
    {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title(PNOSwaggerNotes.TITLE).description(PNOSwaggerNotes.DESCRIPTION)
            .contact(
                new Contact(PNOSwaggerNotes.CONTACT_NAME, PNOSwaggerNotes.CONTACT_URL, PNOSwaggerNotes.CONTACT_EMAIL))
            .version("1.0").build();
    }

Comment: @TechFree Thanks for the suggestion. I started by using ApiInfoBuilder only. I removed that code just to ensure that it is not the cause of my issue. I will revert back to it once I get the solution to my problem.

Comment: Still doesnt work ? Which Spring version?

Comment: @TechFree Spring version 5.1.7.RELEASE (Earlier, I tried with version 5.1.2.RELEASE).

Comment: Any solution, anyone?

Comment: will try today, Boot 2 x?

Comment: @TechFree We are using Spring MVC not Spring Boot.

Comment: sorry did not take a look later, but unable to reproduce your issue. If not resolved, can you please check the gauva version in the resolved dependencies. I have gauva-20.0.jar which works (this library is responsible for resolving the custom vs default apiInfo to use )

Comment: @TechFree We were using guava-27.0.1-jre.jar. But based on your comment, I tried with the version 20.0 as well. It still didn't work.

Comment: @TechFree Thanks for your support. I needed to add the swagger configuration class as a bean. That solved it.

Comment: Great !, I tried with Spring Boot, and embedded config earlier, all this XML config was not required there.

Comment: Right. Actually I found lots of documents and SO questions on swagger with Spring Boot. Finding something for Spring MVC only was quite tough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the servlet config xml file, I needed to add the SwaggerConfiguration class as a bean. I added the following line:

```
<bean class="com.sample.package.SwaggerConfiguration"/>
```

And it worked.